# JavaScript stable sort issue

Tags: javascript

I've looked around for some help on this topic but was unable to find some help or guidance. 
My problem is I am attempting to perform a sort on a series of values separated by an equals sign.

> "Foo=Bar , Shenanigans=Fun, A=B ...etc"

My current sort works, but only if no value is the same. If I have some values like:

> "Foo=Bar, A=Bar, Potato=Bar"

When the sort is complete they will all be "A=Bar"

My current sort looks like this, would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

```js
$('#sortByValue').click(function() {
 var textValueArray = document.getElementById('nameValuePairList');
 textArray = new Array();
 valueArray = new Array();
 oldValues = new Array();
 for (i = 0; i < textValueArray.length; i++) {
  valueArray[i] = textValueArray.options[i].value;
  textArray[i] = textValueArray.options[i].text;
  oldValues[i] = textValueArray.options[i].value;
 }
 valueArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
 });
 for (i = 0; i < textValueArray.length; i++) {
  textValueArray.options[i].value = valueArray[i];
  for (j = 0; j < textValueArray.length; j++) {
   if (valueArray[i] == oldValues[j]) {
    textValueArray.options[i].text = textArray[j];
    j = textValueArray.length;
   }
  }
 }
});
```

I know that my problem lies here: valueArray[i] == oldValues[j]
as when the data comes in valueArray = {Bar, Foo, Bar} while textArray = {Foo=Bar, A=Foo, Test=Bar}

However, I am unsure how to best resolve it.

Comment: What do you want the result of the sort to be?

Comment: For the inputs of { A=C, Test=Bar,Code=Fun, Foo=Bar}
The finished sort should look like. 

{Foo=Bar, Test=Bar, A=C, Code=Fun}
It should sort ascending by what is on the right of the '=' sign.

Comment: Why would you want to even create this? It's doable, but really.

Answer (score 0):

Sort textArray directly, don't use valueArray since it will contain duplicates:

```
textArray.sort(function(a,b){
    var aa = a.split('=')
    var bb = b.split('=')

    var a_key = aa[0].toLowerCase(), a_val = aa[1].toLowerCase();
    var b_key = bb[0].toLowerCase(), b_val = bb[1].toLowerCase();

    if (a_val == b_val) return a_key.localeCompare(b_key);

    return a_val.localeCompare(b_val);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('sortByName').onclick = sortByName;
function sortByName(){
    var myList = document.getElementById('list');
    var values = [];
    for (var i=0;i<myList.options.length;i++) {
        values[i] = myList.options[i].text;
    }
      values.sort(function (a, b){
            if(a !== "" && b !== ""){
                return a.split('=')[0].localeCompare(b.split('=')[0]);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    clearList(myList);

    fillList(myList, values);
}

function clearList(list) {
    while (list.options.length > 0) {
        list.options[0] = null;
    }
}

function fillList(myList, values){
    for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = values[i];
        myList.options[i] = option;
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/56hs2nmn/13/)

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind doing this at all will have you wondering why, in the future. I think you want something like this:

```
function inArray(v, a){
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === v){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function sortWeirdString(str){
  var pairs = str.split(/\s?,\s?/), n = [], v = [], c = [], ci, idx = [], cl, nv = [], ra = [];
  for(var i=0,l=pairs.length; i<l; i++){
    var pair = pairs[i].split(/\s?=\s?/);
    n.push(pair[0]); v.push(pair[1]);
  }
  c = n.concat().sort(); cl = c.length
  for(var i=0; i<cl; i++){
    var cv = c[i];
    if(n.indexOf){
      ci = n.indexOf(cv);
      if(inArray(ci, idx)){
        ci = n.indexOf(cv, ci+1);
      }
      idx.push(ci);
    }
    else{
      for(var x=0; x<cl; x++){
        if(n[x] === cv){
          if(inArray(x, idx)){
            continue;
          }
          idx.push(x);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i=0,l=idx.length; i<l; i++){
    ra.push(c[i]+'='+v[idx[i]]);
  }
  return ra.join(', ');
}
$('#sortByValue').click(function(){
  console.log(sortWeirdString($('#nameValuePairList').val()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2019**

The spec [has changed](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) and [#Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is now a stable sort.

> The elements of this array are sorted. The sort must be stable (that
>   is, elements that compare equal must remain in their original order)

This is already [implemented in V8](https://v8.dev/features/stable-sort)